# Comment entity related to Article or Product

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, relationship

I have entities "Article" and "Product". Now I want to add comments to these 2 entities. Should I create 2 different entities "ArticleComment" and "ProductComment" with the same properties, and build a ManyToOne relation to their respective entity, or create a single "Comment" entity and find a way to build a relation to both "Article" and "Product" entities. Considering solution #2, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering solution #2, how could I do that ?

One way would be to use [Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

> Single Table Inheritance is an inheritance mapping strategy where all classes of a hierarchy are mapped to a single database table. In order to distinguish which row represents which type in the hierarchy a so-called discriminator column is used.

This means that you can easily create two separate entities `ArticleComment` and `ProductComment` both extending `Comment`. Then you use the advantages `DiscriminatorMap` column provides.

Your `Comment` entity could hold a relation called `parent` for instance that would refer to either your `Article` or `Product` entities. By creating new instance of `ArticleComment` or `ProductComment` your discriminator map field would be automatically populated depending on which type you're using.

This would also give you advantages with using DQL to query related comments by their type. Example from documentation:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Doctrine\Tests\Models\Company\CompanyPerson u WHERE u INSTANCE OF Doctrine\Tests\Models\Company\CompanyEmployee');
```

And more. You can read that chapter [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). Of course this is just a sample and you can use completely different approach.

Comment: Is this considered as best practice, when dealing with multi-reference relationships ? And about this discriminator field, what does it looks like ? a string like 'article' or 'product' ? or a class name like '\Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\Product' ?

Comment: It can be anything you like. In most cases is a string which is easy to understand. Normally you cant access the field directly. But if you happen to hold a reference to specific object you will get a full namespace path to its corresponding entitiy based on the type.